want to understand pointer to struct and void pointer conversion
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct person {
    char *name;
    unsigned int age;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int weight; 
} person_t;

int main() {
   
    void *p;
    person_t *p1;
    p = malloc(sizeof(person_t));
    p1 = (person_t *)p;

    p1->name = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p1->name,"my_name"); //edited after rightly pointing in comments
    p1->age=25; p1->height=6; p1->weight=65;

    printf("\n%p -> %u == ",(p+12),*(unsigned int *)(p+12)) ;
    printf("%p -> %u",&p1->height,p1->height) ;

    return 0;
}

Output:
0x16c46b4 -> 6 == 0x16c46b4 -> 6

both prints are printing same pointer and value. Could some one help me to understand it more clearly.
executed above piece of code and understood that from both prints same o/p expected but still not convenienced clearly.

p+12 is illegal in standard C. void does not have a size and you cannot use pointer arithmetics on a void*. You are using some non-standard GCC extension.

Note: p1->name = "my_name"; reassigns the pointer to point somewhere else (the string constant) and leaks the previously allocated memory. To copy strings, use strcpy and similar.

What exactly is unclear with the results? GCC treats a void* as pointing to something with size=1 and the offset of height within your person_t struct seems to be 12.

Draw pictures with boxes (data) and arrows between them (pointer variables whose contents is the address of other data.) If you've read the words in a book and aren't sure, why do you you think more words will be able to help you. Learning means struggling.

Your code is not portable as it relies on some implementation details.
You are using a system, where int seems to have 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits large.
You also do not have padding in your struct. At least not between the first 3 elements.
And finally, you use a non-standard extension in GCC that treats void* as char*.
That means, your memory layout of that struct looks like this:
+--------+------------+--------+
| offset |  field     |  size  |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   0    | char *name |    8   |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   8    | uint age   |    4   |
+--------+------------+--------+
|  12    | uint height|    4   |
+--------+------------+--------+
|  16    | uint weight|    4   |
+--------+------------+--------+

This means, if you take the address of that struct and add 12 bytes, you get the address of height member.
You can verify this by printing offsetof(person_t, height).
If you do &p1->height, the compiler does the calculation for you.
If you do p+12 you do the calculation manually and get the same result.
This relies on the GCC extension that allows using void* for calculation. It does same as if it was char* which means, pointer arithmetics adds single bytes.

"You also do not have padding in your struct." There could be trailing 4 byte padding at the end of struct if name field needs to aligned to 8 byte boundary.

@user694733 right. I extented the statement a bit.
